# Drupal Commerce: Dynamic shipping cost

Tags: commerce

for my marketplace based on Drupal Commerce I need to give to my sellers the possibility to enter their shipping cost so that the buyer will be choice from 1+ alternatives (say postal mail, ups, dhl, etc etc). For insert and retrive there is no problem, I can write a custom module.

My problem is how to give, in "Shipping cost" page, to the buyer the possibility to choice the best (for him/her) shipping cost method. I have tried to use Shipping module with an hacked version of "shipping flat" module but without success.

is there a possibility to do this thing ? I think yes because the old custom eshop in use into that site allowed it.